# Script started by daemon cannot not find shared library

Tags: shell-script, services, ld

I am extending snmpd with the `extend` directive to call some scripts for some OIDs. The script itself calls a custom helper program that gets extracts some value. The helper runs fine when it is started manually from the command line, but when I call it in the script it does not work because it cannot find our custom dependencies in `/cots/boost-1.55/lib`. I have added `/cots/boost-1.55/lib` to `/etc/ld.conf.d/cots.conf` and after running `ldconfig` verified that the boost libraries are in the cache. The script basically contains

```
result=`callHelper with arguments`
echo $result
```

and the result is captured by snmpd and returned. When I query the OID I get an error that it cannot find the external boost library.

I was able to make it work by calling `su user` in the script

```
result=`su user "callHelper with arguments"`
echo $result
```

Can anybody explain why the ld cache is correct when using `su`, but not when the script the program directly? I think it has something to do with the fact that snmpd is a system service and thus the environment is different, but `ldconfig` is not part of the environment.

Comment: restart snmpd from a shell which uses the new ld config.

Comment: I did that. The configuration seems to be ignored completely.

Comment: then try a reboot

Comment: also did that. ldconfig was done a long time ago.

Comment: worst case: result=`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/cots/boost-1.55/lib callHelper with arguments`

Comment: The problem is that the scripts are defined as extensions in snmpd.conf. You can only use a path to an exetucable here, not arbitrary shell commands. I could of add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the scripts, but we have a requirement to not have hard-coded paths in there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check to see if your library is in your search PATH. Run the following in TERM to check your global PATH. Path is setup using `.profile` not config.

```
echo $PATH$
```

to see your search path. To explicitly add your library to your search path use the "set" command in Term. The dollar sign denotes that it is  global call to the shell. Try

```
set PATH=$PATH$;/cots/boost-1.55/lib
```

The semicolon tells the shell to start a new search path. However, this only works if the search path exists. Of course it forks on my machine as with

```
set PATH=$PATH$;/cots/boost-1.55/lib
bash: /cots/boost-1.55/lib: -forks No such file or direc
```

tory!

Comment: Lee, delimiter for path is `:`, not `;`. Path variable in shell should be defined as `$PATH`, not `$PATH$`